# Требуется ли запятая в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

За исключением одного ученика, все прибыли вовремя.

Answer (score 1):

**За исключением одного ученика, все прибыли вовремя.**

[Грамота](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/152-zap-19-33):

> § 154. Запятыми выделяются слова и группы слов, ограничивающие или
>   уточняющие смысл предыдущих или следующих за ними слов и
>   присоединяемые к ним непосредственно или посредством слов: в том
>   числе, включая, исключая, **за исключением**...